# What's the best practice fo saving states during navigation across Fragments in an Activity AND refreshing data across all the Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, navigation

So my current implementation is as follows. Basically I preload all the fragments, set them as fields of the current `Activity`, then I add or show if the fragment was already added.

```
    mFeedTopicsFragment = FeedTopicsFragment.getInstance();
    mUserDiscussionsFragment = UserDiscussionsFragment.getInstance(SessionPersistor.getSignedInUserId());
    mUserConversationsFragment = MyConversationsFragment.getInstance(SessionPersistor.getSignedInUserId());

    activityMainNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener((MenuItem item) -> {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item_go_to_feed_fragment:
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FeedTopicsFragment.class.getSimpleName()) != null) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .show(mFeedTopicsFragment)
                            .hide(mUserDiscussionsFragment)
                            .hide(mUserConversationsFragment)
                            .commit();
                } else {
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.activity_main_container_fragment, mFeedTopicsFragment, FeedTopicsFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                            .hide(mUserDiscussionsFragment)
                            .hide(mUserConversationsFragment)
                            .commit();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_item_go_to_user_discussions_fragment:
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(UserDiscussionsFragment.class.getSimpleName()) != null) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .show(mUserDiscussionsFragment)
                            .hide(mFeedTopicsFragment)
                            .hide(mUserConversationsFragment)
                            .commit();
                } else {
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.activity_main_container_fragment, mUserDiscussionsFragment, UserDiscussionsFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                            .hide(mFeedTopicsFragment)
                            .hide(mUserConversationsFragment)
                            .commit();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_item_go_to_user_conversations_fragment:
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyConversationsFragment.class.getSimpleName()) != null) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .show(mUserConversationsFragment)
                            .hide(mFeedTopicsFragment)
                            .hide(mUserDiscussionsFragment)
                            .commit();
                } else {
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.activity_main_container_fragment, mUserConversationsFragment, MyConversationsFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                            .hide(mFeedTopicsFragment)
                            .hide(mUserDiscussionsFragment)
                            .commit();
                }
                return true;
```

However, I feel this is a bad approach since I'm wasting memory by preloading the fragments. However, I don't want to call `replace` each `FragmentTransaction` as that will call `onCreateView` each time and force a fresh API call each time I navigate between the fragments. I don't want this, as long as I remain in this `Activity`, say I start on `FeedTopicsFragment`, scroll down to the 10th item in the `RecyclerView`, navigate from `FeedTopicsFragment` to `UserDiscussionsFragment`, scroll down to the third item in the `RecyclerView`, and then back to `FeedTopicsFragment`, I will still see the 10th item, and back in `UserDiscussionsFragment`, I will see the third item.

I'm considering using `onSaveInstanceState` to save a `Bundle` of the data and load that `Bundle` in `onActivityCreated`. But I'm afraid `onSaveInstanceState` might not be called, neither will `onActivityCreated`. **So what's the best solution for saving the state without creating an instance of the Fragment or saving it as a field and deleting that state once I navigate away from the Activity?**

Each fragment currently has a `loadData` method that, inside that method, makes a call to the API and sets the `RecyclerView`, `TextView`, etc fields with the response data. Once I do a `SwipeRefresh` inside the Activity, it will call `loadData` on each of the Fragments.

**I'm not sure how to do this refresh part either, basically I have to get an instance of all the Fragments and then call `loadData` on each of them. But only one fragment is in the `activity_main_container_fragment` at a time. In this case, I guess it makes sense to save an instance of each of the Fragments so then I can just call `loadData` on those local instances.**

Comment: There have been various approaches aiming to avoid making an API call every time a Fragment is attached to an Activity: retained Fragments, Loader/ LoaderManager (takes getting used to but does a good job of decoupling loading from presenting) and finally (up to now): [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html) etc. I think it will be worth your while to learn how to use them in your app.

Comment: what is retained fragments? Just saving the fragment by tag in FragmentManager?

Comment: No, not at all. A retained Fragment will not be destroyed if a [configuration change](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) happens. Usually it does not (should not) have any Views

Comment: Still don't understand retained Fragments. Do you have a link to some resources on it I can look at?

Comment: Just click on "configuration change" (you can't have read all of it in 5 secs)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can check your Arraylist if null or empty before calling api.

> if list has data then fill in listview locally,
>
> else call api for getting data.

if you load fragment from stack then it will have its all variables like arraylist too.

First of all you should consider calling this method to replace your Fragment, because i saw you wrote too much code.

```
/**
     * replace or add fragment to the container
     *
     * @param fragment pass android.support.v4.app.Fragment
     * @param bundle pass your extra bundle if any
     * @param popBackStack if true it will clear back stack
     * @param findInStack if true it will load old fragment if found
     */
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, @Nullable Bundle bundle, boolean popBackStack, boolean findInStack) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        String tag = fragment.getClass().getName();
        Fragment parentFragment;
        if (findInStack && fm.findFragmentByTag(tag) != null) {
            parentFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        } else {
            parentFragment = fragment;
        }
        // if user passes the @bundle in not null, then can be added to the fragment
        if (bundle != null)
            parentFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        else parentFragment.setArguments(null);
        // this is for the very first fragment not to be added into the back stack.
        if (popBackStack) {
            fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        } else {
            ft.addToBackStack(parentFragment.getClass().getName() + "");
        }
        ft.replace(R.id.contenedor_principal, parentFragment, tag);
        ft.commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }
```

use it like

If your fragment is home or dashboard fragment then

```
Fragment f = new YourFragment();
replaceFragment(f, null, true, true);
```

Otherwise

```
Fragment f = new YourFragment();
replaceFragment(f, null, false, true);
```